# Rebooting android using monkeyrunner

Tags: android, adb, jython, monkeyrunner, reboot

I have this application which I'm testing. I use a script which automatically installs the app but I also want to restart the device. This is important as after the installation I run a monkey-test on the device and all kind of quirks and bugs may arise. To get rid of these I want to restart the phone to get it into some kind of "known state". (These bugs are not only in the app as the phone has been known to suddenly shutdown during the tests)

My installation script is run with jython and I know of the `device.reboot()` command but this takes almost no time at all (which makes me suspicious) and doesn't work very well. I know there's three arguments: "bootloader", "recovery" and "None" but I can't find the impact these would have on the device.

So my question is, is `device.reboot()` the right command to use? If yes, what happens when I don't use any arguments with the `device.reboot()` command and what is the effects of the arguments.

It may be worth mentioning that I run the jython script from a batch command prompt in jenkins. So any batch commands using adb or similar would work just as fine.

Comment: Is that different than device.reboot()?

Comment: Is equal to `device.reboot("None")`

Comment: Ah, alright. If I leave it empty like device.reboot(), is that the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

device.reboot("None") works on my device